# Surveymonkey API: per_page defaults and max

Tags: surveymonkey

We are calling the `/contacts` API for SurveyMonkey.  Docs are [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#contacts).  We need to get all active contacts, and I'm wondering about the paging feature.  If we don't specify a `per_page` parameter, will we truly get all active contacts?  Or will we get the first page only?  There is no default listed for `per_page`, unfortunately, so I don't know how it will act.

A quick follow-up to this is wondering if there is a max for this field.  If there is a default `per_page`, and I need to mess with paging, what is the max I can set `per_page` to?

We currently don't have a ton of contacts so it's tough to test the defaults/max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all list endpoints unless specified otherwise can accept a max page size of `1000` resources as specified under [Request and Response Limits](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#request-and-response-limits). Perhaps that should (also?) be under [Pagination](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#pagination). Some [bulk endpoints](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses-bulk) for example, have a max page size of `100`.

I don't see in the docs what the page size is by default, but it is `50`. So if you don't specify the number of resources to return, you will get up to `50` back.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Yes, having this information under the Pagination section would help quite a bit.  It would help even more if the proper defaults/max's were under each endpoint that deals with paging since they aren't consistently applied.